# Hot water line under my laundry tub leaking at the crimped joint just before it goes into the wall

Tags: water, leak

[image]I am a senior woman living on a pension.  My hot water line to the laundry tub has been turned off for a year now because of a leak.  Three plumbers plus a new faucet later and I still have the issue.  Today the plumber told me that he would have to cut a hole in the drywall to fix the leak. He took this picture and told me to go to Home Depot and ask them for the part that he needs. Can someone help me because plumbers are definitely not cheap.

Comment: It's good he's a plumber and not a photographer! Can't tell much from the picture. Is the leak soaking the drywall? Typically these leaks are in the shutoff valve or the connection to the valve and not in the wall. Do you have a family member or someone who can look at this for you?

Comment: I hope he's  a better plumber that  photographer...  It's hard to see the problem area from that photo.

Comment: Hi. What part did he ask you to get?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'd love to help, but we'll need more info; please edit it into your question (use the "edit" link). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: The leak is at the joint where the metal piece connects to the plastic piece that goes into the wall...just in front of the collar in the photo.  The plumber didn't ask me to get a specific piece...just asked me to take the picture to Home Depot and ask them what part I needed.

Comment: I have another picture however am not sure how to add it.  My email address is kebrown@shaw.ca and I could add it there.